# sentencia SQL para calcular valor de multa

Tags: mysql, sql

Poseo un sistema para calcular un pago de multas a un usuario, este tiene las dos siguientes tablas: **MULTAS** y **MULTAS_USUARIOS**

> NOTAS:

// En la tabla multas poseo insertados los dos tipos de multas, tanto normales como especiales, solo cambio su tipo. (explicado mas adelante)

// Solo es posible insertar un tipo de multa a los usuarios, o normal o especial.

> TABLA MULTAS:

**tipo_multa:** entero de una cifra, 1=multa normal, 2=multa especial

**num_multa:** distintos numeros de multa para cada multa correspondiente

**valor:** valor de la multa

**descripcion_multa:** describe la multa

> Ejemplo:

**tipo_multa:** 1
**num_multa:** 1
 **valor:** 500
**descripcion_multa:** caminar fuera del rallado

**tipo_multa:** 1
**num_multa:** 2
   **valor:** 1500
  **descripcion_multa:** cruzar en rojo

**tipo_multa:** 1
 **num_multa:** 3
 **valor:** 1300
 **descripcion_multa:** irrespeto al oficial de transito

**tipo_multa:** 2
 **num_multa:** 1
 **valor:** 1000
 **descripcion_multa:** correr por el rallado

**tipo_multa:** 2
 **num_multa:** 2
  **valor:** 2000
 **descripcion_multa:** chocar y salir huyendo

**tipo_multa:** 2
**num_multa:** 3
**valor:** 1700
**descripcion_multa:** golpear al oficial de transito.

> TABLA MULTAS_USUARIOS:

**id_usuario:** numero de identificacion del usuario

**multa_tipo:** llave foranea del tipo de multa

**multa_num:** numero de la multa

**Ejemplo**

**id_usuario:** 25171777
**multa_tipo:** 1
**multa_num:** 1

**id_usuario:** 25171777
**multa_tipo:** 1
**multa_num:** 2

**id_usuario:** 12412421
**multa_tipo:** 2
**multa_num:** 1

**id_usuario:** 12412421
**multa_tipo:** 2
**multa_num:** 2

> Quisiera poder sacar el valor total de la multa sabiendo que para cada usuario se debe sumar los valores que corresponden a cada multa que tenga este guardado en **MULTAS_USUARIOS**.

**Tomando un ejemplo:**

**Usuario:** 25171777:

**tipo de multa:** 1, **numero:** 1 (traidos de **MULTAS_USUARIOS**), **valor:**  500 (traido de **MULTAS**)

**tipo de multa:** 1, **numero:** 2 (traidos de **MULTAS_USUARIOS**), **valor:** 1500 (traido de **MULTAS**)

**Total multas=** 2000

> Es por eso que necesito la sentencia SQL para obtener esos valores y sumarlos, y tambien la formula que deberia emplear

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código es bastante sencillo, simplemente tienes que hacer un `JOIN` entre las tablas y luego usar `SUM`:

```
SELECT  mu.id_usuario,
        SUM(m.valor) AS Total_Multas
FROM MULTAS_USUARIOS AS mu
INNER JOIN MULTAS AS m
    ON mu.multa_num = m.multa_num
WHERE mu.id_usuario = 25171777 
GROUP BY mu.id_usuario
;
```

De todas formas, tu diseño de las tablas tiene un problema, no deberías tener la columna `multa_tipo` en la tabla `MULTAS_USUARIOS`. Esto porque es un "anti-patrón" de diseño. Basta tener el número de la multa en la tabla `MULTAS_USUARIOS`, y el tipo lo obtendrás de la tabla `MULTAS`. En tu diseño actual, no hay nada que impida a nivel de base de datos que un número de multa aparezca con un tipo en la tabla `MULTAS_USUARIOS` y un tipo diferente en la tabla `MULTAS`

Comment: lo que quise hacer fue que al llenar el checkbox de la pagina que genera las multas, esta guarda en un lado al usuario y en otro lado guarda el id del usuario junto al tipo de multa que selecciono (multa_tipo) y luego los dos numeros de multas. porque pense que al llamar a consulta buscarias al usuario y en la tabla multas_usuario y mostrarias sus multas y luego con el tipo identificarias si se trataba de normal o especial buscando en multas

Comment: @VictorA. es un "anti-patrón" de diseño. Basta tener el número de la multa, y el tipo lo obtendrás de la tabla `MULTAS`. En tu diseño actual, no hay nada que impida a nivel de base de datos que un número de multa aparezca con un tipo en la tabla `MULTAS_USUARIOS` y otro en la tabla `MULTAS`

Comment: Entonces Me sugieres hacer la tabla multas con el id_tipo, num_multa y la descripción? Y en multas usuarios que usaría?

Comment: ya entendi el porque, como tenemos USUARIO > MULTA_USUARIO <MULTAS es una tabla anidada :)

Comment: @VictorA. Claro, el único cambio que haría es quitar la columna `multa_tipo` de la tabla `MULTAS_USUARIOS`, porque esa información ya está en la columna `MULTAS`

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias, te puedo hacer una pregunta, si yo subiera un diseño de una base de datos aqui lo podrian corregir?, en el caso del normalizado correcto?, yo lo haria primero y luego para verificar que esten bien las relaciones

Comment: @VictorA. Tengo entendido que preguntas del estilo de modelamiento de datos son aceptadas en el sitio (siempre y cuando cumplan los requisitos mínimos de una buena pregunta)

Comment: entendido, muchas gracias!